# Windows 10 Environment Varibles issue

Tags: environment-variables, windows-10, java-home

I have set JAVA_HOME, CATALINA_HOME, MAVEN_HOME in system variables as sys admin. still after every restart the command line forgets everything and prints like ;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin

Tried  reboot,  shutdown and new start, still the problem remains

Comment: What have you set these variables to? What exactly has been forgotten? What did you expect the command line to print?

Comment: Did you do a reboot or a shutdown and then a new start?

Comment: Let me ask you again: when you say "reboot" was it really a reboot or a shutdown and new start (it makes a difference in Windows 10). What you describe here would happen if you don't reboot.